# PHP / Jquery large XML requests

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, xml

I´m working with an API and have a Problem.

I must send a request and get a new Url as response. This could be a large XML File (more than 10MB) but its not loading correctly.

I tried it with PHP + Caching the large File and the output with Ajax.

What would be the best solution?

Comment: Cut down the amount of data received by each request by using paging.

Comment: downloading that file would be better.

Comment: cut down the amount of data sounds interesting. 
its a flight search api and the best thing would be, if i could have a fast output. the response-xml of the flights is very large.

Comment: If I were you I would split that file and create a queue to downloading that file, You can use Redis and create the response as the list key in Redis.If you are interesting in this idea I would post proper answer with details